# Apache 2.2 rewrite rule for Plone and Zope for intranet portal

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, plone, zope

This question will be mainly for Zope and Plone administrators and developers.

I have been attempting to get an Apache rewrite rule working using documentation from apache, Plone.org, and Zope foundation. I have found small examples but they don't seem to have enough explanation that I can use to apply to my situation. I apologize to anyone who creates documentation for these organizations--the documentation is outstanding. I am just not successfully resolving the problem on my own.

Overview: The context is intranet portal style setup behind a corporate firewall. I am using Apache as a proxy to a plone instance (name = wiki) running on a zeo server (port 8080). I don't want anyone to access the plone site directly through port 8080 for security reasons. I want Apache listening on port 80 to redirect/proxy to the plone site. This will also give me the ability to hide parts of the URL that are too complex for users. I have a separate DNS server that points to the Plone server (Plone hostname = wiki.domain.net) so that some of the address complexity is cut down. Users can type "wiki" to get to the server from within our domain. Keep in mind my boss also required that the plone site name be called "wiki". So, currently users can access plone using the following conventions:

`http://wiki:8080/wiki
http://wiki.domain.net:8080/wiki`

Apache is running but not able to redirect through port 80--effectively someone can just access zope/plone directly on port 8080. I want Apache to pick up the traffic and redirect to the plone instance.

This is the virtual host section of my httpd.conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin admin@wiki.domain.net
       ServerName wiki.domain.net
       ErrorLog logs/wiki.domain.net-error_log
       CustomLog logs/wiki.domain.net-access_log common
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
    </VirtualHost>
```

From my browser I am receiving:

> ```
>    `Bad Request
>
>    Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>    Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at wiki Port 80`
> ```

The Apache error_log: `$ tail -20 error_log`:

> ```
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:20:37 2012] [notice] Digest: done
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:20:37 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.6.2.
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:20:37 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.5.
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:20:37 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.2 
>    mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.5 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:49 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(139958166271968,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:50 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [notice] Digest: done
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.6.2.
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.5.
>    [Fri Jan 13 09:30:51 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 
>   OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.5 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured- 
>   resuming normal operations
> ```

log errors with respect to `$ grep -i proxy`:

> ```
>   ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 14:53:02 2012] [error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (*) failed
>   ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 14:57:44 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/
>   ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 14:57:45 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/favicon.ico
>   ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 14:57:45 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/favicon.ico
>   ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:18:18 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:18:21 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:18:34 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:21:49 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:21:50 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:21:53 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:21:58 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:22:34 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:23:07 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/domain.net:80/VirtualHostRoot/
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:10 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:10 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//favicon.ico
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:20 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//wiki
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:21 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//favicon.ico
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:29 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:25:29 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/VirtualHostRoot//favicon.ico
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:26:40 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot//
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:26:40 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot//favicon.ico
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:26:41 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot//
>  ./domain.net-error_log:[Thu Jan 12 15:26:41 2012] [error] [client 172.18.136.33] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/wiki:80/wiki/VirtualHostRoot//favicon.ico
> ```

All of this is running on a CentOS 6.0 x64 with the standard build configuration and 6 GB memory. The firewall ports are open for 8080, 8081, and 80 (and others). Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: That config seems correct. Is there some error in the error log? if so, please add it here.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'd expect this to work for wiki.domain.net. Since you've posted the question, I assume something's not working. Can you tell us more about what's happening when you try this?

Comment: in the case current answers still does not solve, try to disable selinux. Some times it prevents the ability to use rewrite rules. so: "setenforce 0"

Comment: Giacomo Spettoli: See error log above. I am unable to post it in the comments box. SauZheR: tried disabling selinux, but that didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: The error log you added doesn't help so much. Search for proxy errors on the original file. Your RewriteRule seems right, btw.

Comment: Okay. I update the OP with log errors with respect to "proxy" throughout the logs. It looks like wsgi may be using a different compiled python than the python interpreter used by Zope/Plone. The proxy errors don't give a lot of information. Is there a log setting that I can turn on to make it more verbose? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using mod_wsgi you don't need to proxy

Answer (score 5):

The error that you are facing is due to an enhanced security level in Apache version >2.2 (your is 2.2.15). The solution is to add this in your vhost config:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  <Proxy proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8080/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
  </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

More info:

- http://noenieto.com/blog/plone-and-apache-2.2

Comment: FWIW This is the same answer I gave, only with more restrictions placed on the proxy (which is good).

Comment: Yes, it is similar...that's why I upvoted your answer when I gave mine, Alex ;)

Comment: Giacomo, would you be willing to update the plone.org apache example docs?

Comment: I am preparing my final response with the answers and configurations that worked for me. Stay posted and don't close this yet. I will be able to update this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may have missed out enabling Apache's proxy modules. See step two in this guide: https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/ProxyApacheToZope

Comment: I checked the "LoadModule" area of httpd.conf and find that everything listed in step two from link above--mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, and mod_rewrite--are uncommented correctly and ready to go. Is there anything in addition that I have to do from the command line to enable these modules? I did notice in the Apache error_log that mod_wsgi is using a different compiled version of Python than what Zope/Plone is using. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: No, the python's version used by Apache is completely unconcerned to the one used by Zope/Plone. Apache here is acting as a simple/stupid reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Proxy *>
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
```

inside your virtual host container.

Comment: I don't think that's either necessary or desirable. Using rewrite rules for reverse proxying requires the proxy module (see Laurence's response), but not any proxy directives. Allowing unfiltered proxying potentially allows abuse of your install as an open forward proxy.

Comment: aclark: I added this to my virtual host container; however, this didn't resolve the issue. Thank you though. See above for error log and additional attempts.

Comment: @SteveM Not true and certainly not worth a down vote (wrt to proxy module not requiring a proxy directive, it does in some cases).

Comment: @dwith The error in your logs is the one the above directive *should* fix. As SteveM suggests though, it's a very permissive, so if you get it to work you may want to Proxy only localhost instead of *

Comment: In my mind, a down vote means "don't do this." Creating an open proxy is definitely a "don't do this."

Comment: @SteveM Fair enough, I changed it to "Allow from localhost" does that help? (I'm trying to understand the risk.) Incidentally the person who asked this question is trying to do mod_wsgi which makes the entire issue moot (proxy is not required in the case of mod_wsgi).